# Table function in R with dataframe having value as stringAsFactor True

Tags: r

I am reading a csv file in R with below code:

```
df = read.csv("filename.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactor =T)[-2,]
```

(I have to skip second row, as all values it has zero in second row )
It is reading well by skipping second row of original csv file.

Now i have to count unique value of column so i am using below code:

```
table(df$Column_name)
```

I am getting first entry as 0 with counting 0. so there are total of 249 unique values but i am getting 250 with this extra 0 with 0 counting.

I tried reading same csv file but this time with `stringsAsFactor = False` . and I am getting correct result of table function.

Can anyone explain me why it is showing me extra 0 with 0 counting.

Below is Sample output of R console

```
> content = read.csv('sample.csv')
> content
    Plot  Column
1  first column1
2      0       0
3 second column2
4  third column3
5 fourth column4
> 
> df = read.csv('sample.csv', header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)[-2,]
> df
    Plot  Column
1  first column1
3 second column2
4  third column3
5 fourth column4
> table(df$Column)

      0 column1 column2 column3 column4 
      0       1       1       1       1 
> 
> df1 = read.csv('sample.csv', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)[-2,]
> df1
    Plot  Column
1  first column1
3 second column2
4  third column3
5 fourth column4
> table(df1$Column)

column1 column2 column3 column4 
      1       1       1       1 
> unique(df1$Column)
[1] "column1" "column2" "column3" "column4"
>
```

Comment: When you import it using `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` and there is a `0` in the second row, then that `0` is kept as a level within the factors. When you delete that row, the factors will retain that "0 possible" unless/until you set the levels again, using `factor(...,levels=...)` or `levels<-`. An alternative is to import with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, remove the offending row, then call `factor` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) comments,

> When you import it using stringsAsFactors=TRUE and there is a 0 in the
>   second row, then that 0 is kept as a level within the factors. When
>   you delete that row, the factors will retain that "0 possible"
>   unless/until you set the levels again, using factor(...,levels=...) or
>   levels<-. An alternative is to import with stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
>   remove the offending row, then call factor manually.

Let's try an example with the iris data.

```
data(iris)

## Se all the species.
table(iris$Species)

#>    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>        50         50         50 

## Remove all setosa's (analogous to removing your '0').
iris <- iris[iris$Species != "setosa", ]

## Setosa still in the list.
table(iris$Species)

#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>          0         50         50 

## So just re-factor it to set new factor levels.
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)

## Lets try again.
table(iris$Species)

#> versicolor  virginica 
#>         50         50
```